# Transparet/silent redirect to port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-proxy

I have a homepage http://homepage.com/ which use port 80 using apache2.
I host a SPARQL endpoint at http://homepage.com:8080/sparql/ but I would like to rewrite this to www.homepage.com/sparql including get queries such as:

```
www.homepage.com:8080/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+%7B%5B%5D+a+%3FConcept%7D+LIMIT+100
```

I have played around with Redirect and Rewrite but I am not able to achieve the desired effect. In my .htaccess I exactly have the following:

```
Redirect 301 http://homepage.com/sparql/* http://homepage.com:8080/sparql/*
```

What is the correct way to setup such a redirect?

*Edit: When I write transparent I mean that the URL should stay the same i.e. the port number is hidden.

Comment: What do you mean by transparent redirect?

Comment: Try `Redirect 301 /sparql/ http://homepage:8080/sparql/`

Comment: @anubhava I have added an explanation to the post. Sorry for the bad choice of word :P

Comment: @hjpotter92 This does not seem to have any effects, i still get a 404 when I enter homepage.com/sparql. Are there any additional steps to make this work?

Comment: From `http://homepage.com/sparql/*` to  `http://homepage.com:8080/sparql/*` cannot be silent(transparent) rewrite. URL will indeed change unless you enable `mod_proxy` in your Apache config

Comment: I am guessing it is not enough to enable mod_proxy. I guess I have to add some ProxyPass rule or something?